# SignalR HTTP status 400 multiple clients

Tags: android, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I'm running an application with SignalR 2.2.0 on server side and signalr-java-client (self compiled, last GitHub version) on Android as client.

Currently, there are 4 clients connected to my hub. From time to time, it happens, that all 4 clients simultaneously receive the HTTP status 400 with the message "The connection id is in the incorrect format" (the clients were connected before). I analyzed this multiple times and am not able to find any information/pattern when or why this happens.

The connecten is secured via JWT, the token is definitely valid. When retrieving a new token, the connection is stopped and started again. Apart from this, it is very unlikely that the error is device-related, because the error is thrown at all 4 clients the same time.

I know, this error can occur when the client's Identity changes, but an Identity change for 4 clients the same time seems very unlikely to me.

---

This is the server-code used for authentication (*Deepak* asked).

The following method gets called in my Startup.cs:

```
public static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, string audienceID, string sharedSecret)
{
    byte[] secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(sharedSecret);

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
       new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
       {
           Provider = new MyOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),
           AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
           AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceID },
           IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(Issuer, secret)
            }
       });
}
```

Here's the code of `MyOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` class:

```
class MyOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get's a JWT from querysting and puts it to context
    /// </summary>
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        if (context.Token == null)
        {
            string value = context.Request.Query.Get("auth_token");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))   //token from queryString
            {
                context.Token = value;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

I have to retrieve the token from query string, because additionally to the java-client, a javascript client is used, which is not able to set headers.

Lastly, I secure my hub and some of it's methods with the Authorization attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyExampleRole")]
```

---

This is the client-code for connection:

```
public boolean connect(String url, String token) {

    if (connected) {
        return true;
    }

    try {

        this.hubConnection = new HubConnection(url, "auth_token=" + token, true, logger);

        this.hubProxy = hubConnection.createHubProxy("MyHub");
        this.hubProxy.subscribe(this.signalRMethodProvider);

        this.hubConnection.stateChanged(stateChangedCallback);

        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = this.hubConnection.start();
        awaitConnection.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return true;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e) {

        log.error("connect", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Does anybody have an Idea, how to fix this problem or where I may receive further information?

Thank you very much
-Lukas

Comment: please share your code I may help

Comment: Which code should I share? The project itself is very large.

Comment: signalr authorization class

Comment: See my last edit, it contains the code used for authorization.

Comment: seems fine to me... please share android connection start code.... where you start hub..

Answer (score 0):

seems fine...
possible alteration you can do is change

```
awaitConnection.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

to

```
awaitConnection.done(new Action<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {

                Log.d(TAG, "Hub Connected");
            }
        }).onError(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "SignalRServiceHub Cancelled");

            }
        }).onCancelled(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "SignalRServiceHub Cancelled");

            }
        });
```